# JQuery is not triggering atbar button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a large project and need to fix some accessibility issues.

These is a section which has been generated by https://www.atbar.org/ in a JS format I am not familiar with. The user clicks buttons to change font size, background colour and other html elements to assist them with reading content.

When you click on the buttons with your mouse they work fine. This is an example of how the buttons appear:

```
<li class=“access-button">
    <a title="Decrease Text Size" id="block_accessibility_dec" tabindex=“0">A-</a>
</li>
```

If I focus my Chrome inspector on the link element I can see there is an event listening for my click:

[image]

This appears to trigger the change in font size. I found the code that triggers this click, it is in a JS format that I am not familiar with:

```
M.block_accessibility = {
    init: function(Y, autoload_atbar, instance_id) {
        this.defaultsize = M.block_accessibility.DEFAULT_FONTSIZE; 

        // This event triggers after clicking
        Y.all('#block_accessibility_textresize a').on('click', function(e) {
            if (!e.target.hasClass('disabled')) {
                M.block_accessibility.changesize(e.target);
            }
        });


        // This is the function it runs, it has many cases for all the different buttons.
        changesize: function(button) {
        Y = this.Y;
        switch (button.get('id')) {
            case "block_accessibility_dec":
```

Obviously this is just snippets of the code with comments I added.

What I require is the user to be able to change the font size using just tab and enter, so I added the following JQuery:

```
$("#block_accessibility_dec").keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        $('#block_accessibility_textresize #block_accessibility_dec').click();
    }
});
```

This is not triggering the change in font size. Yet when I click on the button it does? There is probably a really simple solution here but I've been stuck for ages. I tested the .click() on other elements on the screen and it works for them so the JS is definitely executing.

I have also tested:

```
$(this).click();
```

But to no avail.

Comment: Do you have a full sample of the code or a jsfiddle? I could assist you then

Comment: hard to see it without fiddle, because your code should be working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to trigger the click event by the native way:

```
$('#block_accessibility_textresize #block_accessibility_dec')[0].click();
```

**Source:** I tried their demo page together with the chrome inspector and couldn't get the click working with JQuery.
But with the native click event it suddenly worked.

Unfortunately I can't really explain to you, why JQuery doesn't work here. Maybe something with their version (1.11)?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with the following code and add the keyup event. This should work when you press the enter key.

```
 Y.all('#block_accessibility_textresize a').on('click keyup', function(e) {
             if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode ==9) {
                 if (!e.target.hasClass('disabled')) {
                M.block_accessibility.changesize(e.target);
            }
           }



        });
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the following Jquery:

```
$('#block_accessibility_textresize #block_accessibility_dec').trigger("click");
```

Please let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work, thanks for the suggestion though! I did not vote you down, I don't want people being off put and not responding to my question!